# Minify (not transpile) ES2015 code with Gulp

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, minify

How to minify ES2015 code without transpiling it to ES5? The popular `gulp-minify` and `gulp-uglify` modules do not work with simply minifying ES2015 code.

Comment: Could you change the accepted answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39169594/3853934)?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is now possible to minify ES2015 without transpiling the code. [babel minify](https://github.com/babel/minify/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-minify) (previously babili) is a babel preset that does that.

To install do:

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-minify
```

To use it with gulp you do:

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var babel = require('gulp-babel')
gulp.task('default', () => {
  return gulp.src('src/app.js')
  .pipe(babel({presets: ['minify']}))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
})
```

Comment: you need to add `npm install babili --save-dev` to your answer so that we don't have to click off-site

Comment: I also had to do 
`npm install gulp-babel --save-dev` 
and 
`var babel = require('gulp-babel');` 
to make this to work. :)

Comment: and `babili` is now called `babel-minify`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only way to minify ES2015 with gulp is to use `gulp-babel` which will transform ES2015 to "traditional" Javascript and then use `gulp-uglify` and `gulp-minify`.

Learn more at: [gulp-babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel/)

Comment: this answer is no longer current. see the upvote winner

Comment: @nguyên 'cause the response is now deprecated. New one is down comment

Comment: akk, it's bad, I don't agree with answer must correct all-times